# how can I databind a column to a datasource?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datasource

I got table with 1 row and 3 columns(date,time,what), I want 2 of the 3 columns(time,what) in my datasource how can i do that?

```
var table = (from r in socialEvents.AsEnumerable()
                         where r.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date &&
                               r.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1)
                         select r).CopyToDataTable();    

    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataGrid1.Visible = true;
                    DataGrid1.DataSource = table;
                    DataGrid1.DataBind();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that datagrid is a GridView?
then you should be to do something like this

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="what" HeaderText="what" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="time" HeaderText="time"  />        
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Then I see 5 columns (time,what,date,time,what)

Comment: make sure AutoGenerateColumns="false"

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the columns in the select

```
var table = (from r in socialEvents.AsEnumerable()
                         where r.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date &&
                               r.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1)
                         select new {time = r.Field<DateTime>("Date"), what = r.Field<data_type>("what") });
```

Comment: I got a error: (extension)DataTable IEnumerable <a>.CopyToDataTablew<'a> ()  
Anonymous Types: a is a new datatime time...